# Use git rebase to retroactively make commits land on a different branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I have some commits:

```
 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 (HEAD, master)
```

Afterwards I notice Commits 2 & 3 really should have gone on their own branch. They are completely independent of commits 4 and 5 Can I use `git rebase` to make?

```
 - 1 - 4 - 5 (HEAD, master)
    \
     2 - 3 (TestBranch)
```

And most importantly, will the SHA1s for `Commit 2` and `Commit 3` stay the same as they were before the rebase?

Comment: I've modified your commit lists into more standard graphs like you'll see in the git man pages and all over the internet. If you prefer the vertical lists, you're welcome to edit it back - but I'd suggest reversing the order. You had newest on bottom, which is the opposite of the output of commands like `git log`, and of the view in `gitk` and other history viewers. I also assumed that Head was actually `HEAD`, and that you have a branch checked out as well; I named it master.

Comment: Thanks, @Jefromi, for making this question more easily understandable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, note that your desired TestBranch points simply to the current commit 3; you don't have to do anything but `git branch TestBranch <commit 3>` to accomplish that. Remember, branches are just pointers to commits. This should answer your question about the SHA1s of commits 2 and 3. You haven't changed those commits at all, so their SHA1s are of course the same.

To get your current branch (master) where you want it (commits 1, 4, 5), you will indeed rebase. This is a very simple case for its interactive mode. First, run:

```
git rebase -i <commit 1> master     # -i is a synonym for --interactive
```

Git will launch your editor, and show you all of the commits since commit 1 on your master branch (2,3,4,5), along with some hints about what to do. You just need to delete the lines for commits 2 and 3, then save and quit. It will then apply what's left (4 and 5), leaving you with what you want. Of course, if commits 4 and 5 depended on commit 2 or 3, you're going to get merge conflicts when git tries to apply their patches during the rebase.

Note that this *will* change the SHA1s of commits 4 and 5, since the SHA1 of a commit depends on its parent. This will mess with anyone who's pulled that branch. (You have been warned.) Your actual final result would more accurately be described like this:

```
- 1 - 4' - 5' (HEAD, master)
   \
    2 - 3 (TestBranch)
```

Commits 4' and 5' have the same diffs as commits 4 and 5, but have different parents, so they are different commits.

Comment: Wouldn't it pe possible to use `git rebase --onto <commit 1> TestBranch master` instead of the interactive rebase?

Comment: @Sven: Absolutely, yes. I tend to recommend the interactive one because you see exactly what you're doing, though I'd personally likely have done it noninteractively.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out `3`, you can then create a new branch `TestBranch` at that point, and obtain your desired branch.

Then you can go back to branch `master`, and [rebase it interactively](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) with `git rebase -i HEAD~6`, deleting `2` and `3` by removing their lines.

Comment: Why would you use interactive rebase to create TestBranch? You can simply create it at commit 3 directly.

Comment: Exact, I mistakenly believed there were spurious commits between 1 and 3.